# Android Things console not allowing me to create a build

Tags: android, raspberry-pi, android-things, android-things-console

I'm trying to build my first Android Things application. 
To run it on my Raspberry Pi I need to create a build with my application.
The problem happens when I try to add my application to the build. It says "Permission denied". I've tried with two different Google accounts.

Does anyone know what could be the reason?
Is there any way of building it from the command line instead of Android Things console?

[image: Android Things Console App selection]

[image: Android Things Console Error]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out what the problem is.

When we create an Android Things application, all the permissions must be set in the Manifest file. No runtime permission is allowed.

Among my permissions, there was the android.permission.READ_LOGS permission and it seems like Android Things Console doesn't accept an application that contains this permission.

I removed it and I was able to add it.